# combining two regex - lambda functions into one

Tags: python, regex, lambda

I'd like to combine two regex functions to clean up my data frame. Assume I've the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
time = ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "33:00"]
result = ["+52", "+62", "+44 - 10a10", "+44", "+30 - $1200", "110"]
data = pd.DataFrame({'time' : time, 'result' : result})
```

`data` looks like this.

```
    result        time
0   +52           09:00
1   +62           10:00
2   +44 - 10a10   11:00
3   +44           12:00
4   +30 - $1200   13:00
5   110           33:00
```

First, I want to remove the `+` sign. Second, I want to remove the `-` sign and everything after it. I can accomplish that with two functions.

```
import re
data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: re.sub('\+', '', x))
data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: re.sub('\-.*', '', x))
```

`data` now looks like this.

```
    result  time
0   52      09:00
1   62      10:00
2   44      11:00
3   44      12:00
4   30      13:00
5   110     33:00
```

Is there a way to do all the replacements in one step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the or (`|`) in the RegEx and do both the operations in one shot, like this

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\+|-.*', '', 'a+b+c-d+f-g')
'abc'
```

So, in your case, the lambda function would be

```
data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: re.sub('\+|-.*', '', x))
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply the same function to more than one column in the data frame (columns are not necessarily next to each other) in one step? Obviously, this does NOT work: `data[[col1, col2]].apply(lambda x: re.sub('\+|-.*', '', x))`.

Comment: @sedeh Sorry! I don't have much idea about pandas. Perhaps you might want to ask that as a separate question.